# Printing to a progress bar to the terminal from Java/C++

Tags: linux, terminal, java, c++

I want to update the percentage progress of my program on the screen.

I have a progress bar that I print. I add a `*` when the progress is more than 10%, but I also want to write the actual percentage correct up to every digit. However, I do not want to write a new number every time, since it will have the following effect:

```
1  
2  
3  
4
```

Instead, I would like to just maintain one single figure on the screen that keeps getting updated.

How do I do that? (… in Java/C++, but I think it's irrelevant)

Comment: Can you share the code you already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ I believe you want to throw \r to bring you back to the beginning of the line (instead of \n) or you'll want to look at the curses library. Not sure, but you can probably do something similar in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Outputting a `\b` will move the cursor back one column, and outputting a `\r` will return it to the first column. From there you can print the new value to be displayed.

```
std::cout << "111\r22\r3" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

For C++, I think the curses offers textual GUIs or something... somewhere someone has already written a textual based progress bar, you should use their implementation so you don't have to do their work over again.

Also, if you didn't know it, java has a progress bar that you can use.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html